# Alpine.JS carousel's prev arrow does not work

Tags: javascript, php, magento2, alpine.js

I've add this custom carousel inside a Magento2 (Hyva Theme), but the left arrow does not work at all.

The right one (next) is working properly and smooth, but clicking over the left arrow (prev) the carousel don't move back.

This is the HTML (rendered with PHP)

```
<div x-data="subcategoriesCarousel()" x-init="init()"
>
    <?php if ($options['enabled']): ?>
        <?php if (!empty($categories)): ?>
            <?php if ($heading): ?>
                <h3 class="apptrian-subcategories-heading"><?= /* @noEscape */ $heading ?></h3>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <ul  x-ref="container" class="apptrian-subcategories-<?= /* @noEscape */ strtolower($options['layout']) ?> scroll-snap-x no-scrollbar"><?php
                foreach ($categories as $c): ?><li class="apptrian-subcategories-category-wrapper"><?php

// Above line with opening <ul> tag and below line with closing </ul> tag
// must be written like this so there are no spaces between <li> tags.

                    $info        = '';
                    $image       = $c['image'];
                    $name        = $c['name'];
                    $description = $c['description'];
                    $url         = $c['url'];

                    if ($singleLink) {
                        $info .= '<a class="apptrian-subcategories-category" href="' . $url . '">';

                        foreach ($elements as $el) {
                            switch ($el) {
                                case 'image':
                                    $info .= '<div class="apptrian-subcategories-category-image"><img src="' . $image
                                        . '" loading="lazy" alt="' . $name . '"' . $imageAttributes . '/></div>';
                                    break;
                                case 'name':
                                    if ($name) {
                                        $info .= '<div class="apptrian-subcategories-category-name"><span>' . $name . '</span></div>';
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case 'description':
                                    if ($description) {
                                        // If description attribute
                                        if ($options['description'] == 'description') {
                                            $info .= '<div class="apptrian-subcategories-category-description">' . $description . '</div>';
                                            // If meta_description attribute
                                        } else {
                                            $info .= '<div class="apptrian-subcategories-category-description"><span>' . $description
                                                . '</span></div>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                        }

                        $info .= '</a>';
                    } else {
                        $info .= '<div class="apptrian-subcategories-category">';

                        foreach ($elements as $el) {
                            switch ($el) {
                                case 'image':
                                    $info .= '<div class="apptrian-subcategories-category-image"><a href="' . $url . '"><img src="'
                                        . $image . '" loading="lazy" alt="' . $name . '"' . $imageAttributes . '/></a></div>';
                                    break;
                                case 'name':
                                    if ($name) {
                                        $info .= '<div class="apptrian-subcategories-category-name"><a href="' . $url . '"><span>'
                                            . $name . '</span></a></div>';
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case 'description':
                                    if ($description) {
                                        // If description attribute
                                        if ($options['description'] == 'description') {
                                            $info .= '<div class="apptrian-subcategories-category-description">' . $description . '</div>';
                                            // If meta_description attribute
                                        } else {
                                            $info .= '<div class="apptrian-subcategories-category-description"><span>' . $description
                                                . '</span></div>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                        }

                        $info .= '</div>';
                    }

                    /* @noEscape */ echo $info; ?></li><?php
                endforeach; ?></ul>

        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="arrows">
        <div @click="scrollTo(prev)">
            <div><</div>
        </div>
        <div @click="scrollTo(next)">
            <div>></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the Alpine.JS script right after

```
<script>
    function subcategoriesCarousel()
    {
        return {
            container: null,
            prev: null,
            next: null,
            init() {
                this.container = this.$refs.container

                this.update();

                this.container.addEventListener('scroll', this.update.bind(this), {passive: true});
            },
            update() {
                const rect = this.container.getBoundingClientRect();

                const visibleElements = Array.from(this.container.children).filter((child) => {
                    const childRect = child.getBoundingClientRect()

                    return childRect.left >= rect.left && childRect.right <= rect.right;
                });

                if (visibleElements.length > 0) {
                    this.prev = this.getPrevElement(visibleElements);
                    this.next = this.getNextElement(visibleElements);
                }
            },
            getPrevElement(list) {
                const sibling = list[0].previousElementSibling;

                if (sibling instanceof HTMLElement) {
                    return sibling;
                }

                return null;
            },
            getNextElement(list) {
                const sibling = list[list.length - 1].nextElementSibling;

                if (sibling instanceof HTMLElement) {
                    return sibling;
                }

                return null;
            },
            scrollTo(element) {
                const current = this.container;

                const nextScrollPosition =
                    element.offsetLeft +
                    element.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2 -
                    current.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2;

                current.scroll({
                    left: nextScrollPosition,
                    right: nextScrollPosition,
                    behavior: 'smooth',
                });
            }
        };
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You are using the `next` variable for the back button as well.

Comment: Yes I was trying to debug, but even with `prev` it does not work, EDITED, thanks!

Comment: Is this a JS problem, a PHP problem, or a Magento problem? Please try to work with static markup first to rule that out

Comment: I think it's a JS problem, otherwise even the next button should not work properly

Comment: If you think that, please check it. Sharing the **generated** markup could help, such that others can reproduce the problem